# pandas map dictionary to column that has tuples in list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, tuples

I have list of tuple in each row of Pandas dataframe. I am trying to apply the first element of the tuple in a list to a dictionary's value. I found regex way to do it however, it doesn't seem like an ideal way to write a code. I am wondering if there is better way to handle it than what I am doing in Try#1?

```
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas as pd

# sample data
l1 = ['1','2','3']
l2 = ['test1','test2','test3']
l3 = [[(1,0.95)],[(2,0.10),(3,0.20)],[(3,0.30)]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':l1,'text':l2,'score':l3})
print(df)

#Preview: 
id   text                 score
1  test1           [(1, 0.95)]
2  test2  [(2, 0.1), (3, 0.2)]
3  test3            [(3, 0.3)]

di = {1:'Math',2:'Science',3:'History',4:'Physics'}

Try #1: Does the trick but it laborious, manual, and not ideal way.
 
df['score'].astype(str).str.replace('1,','Math,').str.replace('2,','Science,').str.replace('3,','History,').str.replace('4,','Science,')

Try#2: Getting all NaNs even if I convert to string.
df["score"].astype(str).map(di)


Looking for the output like this: 
   #Preview: 
    id   text                 score
    1  test1           [(Math, 0.95)]
    2  test2           [(Science, 0.1), (History, 0.2)]
    3  test3           [(History, 0.3)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension could help out here; also Pandas efficiency is somewhat hampered when other data structures are embedded in it.

```
df["score"] = [[(di[left], right) 
                 for left, right in entry] 
                 for entry in df.score]
df


    id  text    score
0   1   test1   [(Math, 0.95)]
1   2   test2   [(Science, 0.1), (History, 0.2)]
2   3   test3   [(History, 0.3)]
```

Comment: It is giving me `KeyError: 1`

Comment: are you running it with the same data you shared?

Comment: Yes. I re-ran the with your code and the same data. But I restarted my Jupyter notebook wiped it. Apparently, there somethings in memory it caused an issue. Its working now for this data. Thanks for such clean solution to deal with the tuples mapping with dictionary!

Comment: glad it worked. Dont forget to upvote and accept. Cheers, mate